# How to create reqular expression to match all numbers without the numbers at the beginning and end of the string?

Tags: ruby, regex

Example code:

```
test = '12asiudas8787hajshd986q756tgs87ta7d6-12js01'
test.scan(regexp)
```

As a result, I should get:

```
["8787", "986", "756", "87", "7", "6", "12"]
```

Like using a `/\d+/` regexp, but without the numbers at the beginning and end of the string, in this case 12 and 01.

Comment: `"12asiudas8787hajshd986q756tgs87ta7d6-12js01".scan(/\d+/)[1..-2]
`

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Are there always numbers at the beginning and the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the numbers **within** the string use following regex.

**Regex:** `(?<=[^\d])(\d+)(?=[^\d])`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=[^\d])` Will ensure that it's not followed by a digit. Without this `2` of `12` at beginning will be matched too, and we don't want that.
- `(\d+)` matches your number.
- `(?=[^\d])` Will ensure that last digit is not followed by a digit. Without this `0` of `01` will be matched too.

**P.S:** Edited regex on [Wiktor Stribiżew's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) advice

One can also use `\D` instead of `[^\d]`. I used `[^\d]` to make it clear.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tF3oI7/1)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[Edited Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tF3oI7/2)**</kbd>

Comment: Some perfectionist downvoted this answer, but it is a perfectly valid answer. Surely `/(?<=\D)\d+(?=\D)/` is shorter, but it is an absolute synonym of this solution (if you remove the capturing group around the `\d+`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You see am still learning and SO being an 8 year old community will give some hard time. Thanx for the suggestion though !

Answer (score 1):

```
test.scan(/(?<=\D)\d+(?=\D)/) # => ["8787", "986", "756", "87", "7", "6", "12"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
test.scan(/(?<=[^\d])(\d+)(?=[^\d])/).flatten
```

Comment: Seems like a subset `(?<!^)(?<=[^\d])(\d+)(?=[^\d])(?!$)`.

Comment: @noob: When you write `(?<=[^\d])` you require a non-digit character to be before the digit matched. That means that `(?<!^)` will always be true and is thus redundant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes I got that now.